# Navigation bar back button text is not displaying properly, when view tiltle is long

Tags: ios7

In IOS7 Navigationbar **back button text is not displaying properly, when viewcontroller title is long.** Image as follows, You can see the **back button text is cut**.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its solved, when i change **pushviewcontrol** code **animated** property from **No to YES**

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:vController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should automatically resize the navigation title:

```
self.title = @"SOME REALLY LONG NAVIGATION BAR TITLE";
UILabel* label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 40)];
label.text=self.navigationItem.title;
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
self.navigationItem.titleView=label;
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, Still the problem is happening.

Comment: can you post the code that you are using to create the navigation bar and title?